# List of object references in python

Tags: python, list, reference

I'm aware that this question has already been asked here in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196463/python-create-list-of-object-references) form or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427310/how-to-implement-a-list-of-references-in-python), but none of the answers address the behaviour I'm seeing. I'm given to understand that a list of objects should only hold *references* to those objects. What I observe seems to contract this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.value=val

a = Foo(2)
b = [a]
print b[0].value

a = Foo(3)
print b[0].value
```

I expect to see `2` printed first, then `3`, since I expect `b[0]` to point to `a`, which is now a new object. Instead I see `2` and `2`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, assignment operator binds the result of the right hand side expression to the name from the left hand side expression.

So, when you say

```
a = Foo(2)
b = [a]
```

you have created a `Foo` object and refer it with `a`. Then you create a list `b` with the reference to the `Foo` object (`a`). That is why `b[0].value` prints `2`.

But,

```
a = Foo(3)
```

creates a new `Foo` object and refers that with the name `a`. So, now `a` refers to the new `Foo` object not the old object. But the list still has reference to the old object only. That is why it still prints 2.

Answer (score 4):

`b[0]` points to the object you initially created with `Foo(2)`.  When you do `a  = Foo(3)`, you create a new object and call it `a`.  You did not change `b` in any way.

The behavior is because of exactly what you said: `b` holds a reference to an *object*.  It does not hold hold a reference to the *name* you used to refer to that object.  So the object in `b[0]` does not know anything about any variable called `a`.  Assigning a new value to `a` has no effect on `b`.